# Scheduling a timed background task in windows 8.1 store app

Tags: c#, background-process, windows-8.1

I have a list of of StringsDouble called Messages.

The code for the class is below:

```
public class StringsDouble
{
    public string Sender {get; set;}

    public string Message {get; set;}

    public DateTime Time {get; set;}  
}
```

every time my app receives a new message. I update the List and i store the time of the latest message sent for the user sending that message.

what i want to do is, every 5 minutes the app should go through the list.

and for every item in the list it should get the time property and get the current system time , and check to see if the difference is more than 30 minutes. If it is, it should delete that item from the list.

How can i accomplish this?

I believe i need to use a background task, but how can i schedule it to run every 5 minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DispatcherTimer` on UI thread:

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
timer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
{
    //...
};
timer.Start();
```

or `ThreadPoolTimer` on a background thread:

```
ThreadPoolTimer threadPoolTimer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer((source) =>
{
    //...            
}, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to run your backgroundtask every 5 minutes.

Maybe push notification can help you? It has a price as you can guess but you can send them any time, any frequency.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples

You can download these samples, there is a sample code for push notifications too.

Answer (score 0):

This link (with code) seems to suggest that you can spread out the 2 seconds of CPU that is assigned to your app every 15 mins. You can therefore run some code in your background task more frequently than every 15 mins:

https://developer.qualcomm.com/blog/windows-8-background-tasks-part-3-make-most-cpu-usage-quota